# Starting new project in Ionic

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

[image]

In Ionic, when I'm starting a new project, it shows me this message: 
‘Would you like to integrate your new app with Cordova to target native iOS and Android’
What does it mean?

Comment: Let me know if I've answered your question correctly or if you require further clarifications

Comment: Ionic is merely a framework built on top of angular to develop mobile pages. But since it is all Javascript it cannot access any device’s native functionality. So it needs a “plugin” that will allow it talk to the host device and its elements, say a camera or anything else. That plugin is Cordova, mostly a set of jar files and you would need different flavours of the plugin for each platform, namely Windows, android or iOS.

Comment: You could've googled to find out more about cordova. The information is available out there .

Comment: The message is self-explanatory. Its unclear what you are trying to do with Ionic/Cordova here and what explanation you need

Answer (score 2):

Ionic uses Cordova to build the apps for android and iOS. If you intend to publish the app on Android or iOS, you need Cordova. It is the glue that binds the JavaScript to the native code.

So it is just asking you if you want to create a mobile application (android and/or iOS). If that's your intention, then hit the y key, followed by enter. It will then ask you which platforms you want to install, type a platform name from the options and hit the enter key again.

If your intent is not to create a mobile app, then hit the n key, followed by enter and you'll be on your way to developing a single page, mobile first application.

Answer (score 0):

it is asking you if you want to create an android application and/or ios application. According to your intention you can give y/n